# What is the remainder of dividing $(116+17^{17})^{21}$ by $8$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> What is the remainder of dividing $(116+17^{17})^{21}$ by $8$?

How to solve this? Solving the congruence (find the value of $a$) in $$(116+17^{17})^{21}\equiv a\pmod8$$ and how is this done?

Comment: @marcelopjunior this is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $17\equiv1\pmod 8,17^{17}\equiv1\pmod 8$ and $116\equiv4\pmod 8$

$\displaystyle\implies 116+17^{17}\equiv 4+1\pmod8\equiv5$

$\displaystyle\implies(116+17^{17})^{21}\equiv 5^{21}\pmod8 $

Now, $\displaystyle5^2=25\equiv1\pmod 8\implies 5^{21}=5\cdot(5^2)^{10}\equiv5\cdot1^{10}\pmod 8\equiv5$

Comment: Incrible, tank you!!!

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, my pleasure

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  The stuff inside the parentheses is odd.  Any odd number squared is $\equiv 1 \pmod 8$

Comment: Remainder may be $1$ or $5$ how u can conclude that it must be one?

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi: No, what can you square to get $5 \pmod 8?$

Comment: Here power is odd$(21)$ which is not square of any integer.

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi:  It allows you to replace the power $21$ with the power $1$ as any odd to the $20$ power is $1$.  Then you can work on the inside.

Comment: check the third ans. i wan not wrong

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi:  I didn't say the final answer wasn't $5$.  I was getting OP started.  As I said, this takes care of the $21$.  Then noticing that $17 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ lets you know the inside is equivalent to $117 \pmod 8$, which is $5$.  I think this is the easy way.

Comment: You don't even need to observe that $17 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ since $17$ is odd and you can apply your hint again :)